# How to escape ? character in jdbc stored procedure calls

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, jdbc, escaping

I would like to call this stored procedure with jdbc:

```
sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

JDBC thinks the ? is a placeholder for an argument. In fact it is used by the SP to put in the table name. How can I call the stored procedure? I tried this:

```
CallableStatement call = jdbcConnection.prepareCall("call sp_msforeachtable(?)");
call.setString(1, "\"ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all\"");
call.executeUpdate();
```

and I get a syntax error near '@P0'. I guess '@P0' is the ?. How can I call this SP? I am using SQL Server 2008 BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the `?` is supposed to be for a table name, so you need to provide an actual table name before calling `Statement.executeUpdate()`.  At that point the JDBC driver will tell the database to actually run the statement, so obviously all parameters need to be bound.

Maybe you meant to write this:

```
CallableStatement call = jdbcConnection.prepareCall("call sp_msforeachtable(?)");
call.setString(1, "AnActualTableName");
call.executeUpdate();
```

or maybe you meant to write this:

```
CallableStatement call = jdbcConnection.prepareCall("call sp_msforeachtable(\"ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all\")");
call.setString(1, "AnActualTableName");
call.executeUpdate();
```

I'm not sure exactly what `sp_msforeachtable()` is supposed to do, but I do know that you have to provide values for all parameters before calling `executeUpdate()`